# PHP: Get value out of array

Tags: php, arrays

Simple probably but can't get it right. I need a value out of an session array here's how its build:

```
print_r($_SESSION); //gives:

Array
(
    [cart] => cart Object
        (
            [config] => Array()
            [maincurrency:cart:private] => GBP
         )
)
```

The code so far:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $category => $thing) { 

    echo $category; //echo's config |the value I need GBP
    echo $thing; // echo's Array

if ($category == 'maincurrency:cart:private')
    {
        echo 'found_it'; //doesn't echo
        echo $category; //echo's nothing |the value I need GBP
        echo $thing; // echo's nothing

    }
}
```

The string I need is 'GBP' from maincurrency:Test:private.

Comment: does $category echo 'maincurrency:Test:private'?

Comment: You have a semi-colon at the end of your if-statement that you should remove (I'm sure this is only in the post, not the actual code).

Comment: Does $_SESSION['test']['maincurrency:Test:private'] equal GBP?

Comment: something's not right with your condition if `$category` is outputting `config` right there...or your `print_r` of `$_SESSION['test']` doesn't match what you're saying.

Comment: You are sure that `$_SESSION['test']` is the containing array?

Comment: The actual array it quite big, I'll double check the questions above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SESSION['test']` is not an array - it is an object of `Test` class with property `maincurrency` which access is limited to `private` - it means you can not directly access this property.

To get it's value you have either:

- change access of property to `public` in class definition
- create getter function for this property and use it to get it's value

Comment: Thank you. Didn't knew that. I'm gone write some extra code then.